# Birthday Problem Variation : Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

Three friends find out their birthdays are all within the same week.

Supposing their birthdays are otherwise random, what is the probability they all have their birthday on the same day?

Logical Approach : Since its given that birthdays are in same week the sample space is reduced to 7 possibilities for a person. Hence total possibilities = 7^3
Favorable cases  = 7*1*1.    So answer = 1/49

If I go by formula,  let A = probability three have birthday in same day
B = probability three have birthday on same week
Then we have to find P(A|B) = P(A∩B)/P(B)
My question is how do I calculate this if I go by this method?

Comment: In your case P(A∩B)=P(A)

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)=(365*1*1)/365^3=1/365^2$ and $P(B)=(52*1*1)/52^3=1/52^2$. Therefore, you get
$$P(A|B)=\frac{(1/365^2)}{(1/52^2)}=\frac{52^2}{365^2}=\left(\frac{52}{365}\right)^2\approx\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^2=\frac{1}{49}$$

Comment: 52*7 = 364 right?

Comment: yeah. I'll edit.

Comment: Why aren't the both case equal? I mean we get exactly 1/49 in one but approximately 1/49 in other

Comment: Well, there is one day of the year that belongs to its own week. If this is the week that the birthdays fall on, there is a 100% chance they will have the same birthday. That is not reflected in the answer in your post. Also, maybe it's a leap year...